# How to Git merge two separate copies (but with some different features) of the same app from different PCs

Tags: git

I started working on a small web app on my laptop, I installed Git and created a repo (did not push to Bitbucket).

I later purchased a desktop installed Git and **copied all the files from the laptop and continued working**. At about 75% through the desktop motherboard crashed so now I have to revert to the laptop.

I went back to the laptop(older version of app) and added new featured that are different to the ones on the desktop and **pushed to Bitbucket** and launched to app.

**Question:** How can I add the features from the crashed desktop version to the launched version?

**N.B.** I can take the hard drive out of the desktop and attach it to the laptop as an external.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Laptop: Assume all your commits/changes are in `master` branch. Push `master` to remote BitBucket (skip it if already done).

  ```
  $ git checkout master
  $ git push origin master
  ```
- Create a new branch (say, `desktop`) from `master` branch.

  ```
  $ git checkout -b desktop        # create & checkout to 'desktop' branch
  ```
- Now copy your Project folder/files from your desktop to laptop (**except `.git` folder**). You can use Pendrive or else. Replace all the laptop project files with Desktop project files (**make sure you would not copy `.git` folder from desktop**)
- Now `Add`, `Commit` your changes. (`desktop` branch)

  ```
  $ git add .
  $ git commit -m 'Desktop changes'
  ```
- Now `Merge` your `master` branch with your `desktop` branch. (`desktop` branch)

  ```
  $ git pull origin master
  ```
- Now if conflict occurs then resolve it. You can manually resolve conflicts. You can also use `ours` (keep `desktop` changes) or `theirs` (keep `master` changes).

  ```
  $ git checkout --ours -- .       # keep 'desktop' branch changes
  or,
  $ git checkout --theirs -- .     # keep 'laptop' branch changes
  ```
- Now `Add`, `Commit`, `Push` the changes. (`desktop` branch)

  ```
  $ git commit -am 'Fix conflicts'     # add & commit
  $ git push origin HEAD               # update remote/desktop
  ```
- Merge `desktop` branch with `master` branch.

  ```
  $ git checkout master

  $ git pull origin desktop     # pull = fetch + merge,  pull `desktop` changes into 'master' branch 
  $ git push origin HEAD        # update remote/master
  ```

Now, in `master` branch you have all the features of `laptop` and `desktop`. Launch your app from `master` branch.